# Why does every T-800 Terminator sent back look like this?

Tags: the-terminator, terminator-2-judgment-day, the-terminator-series

Why did they all look like this?

[image]

OK, OK, OK, I realize that the main plot to the story involved Arnold schwarzenegger as the actor so it had to look like this.

But my query is that in the first Terminator, they used dogs to detect terminators and the one that broke through the defenses looked nothing like the other T-800's,

So was there anything canon that stated why all the Terminators that were sent back looked the same?

Comment: Possible dupe of [Why did the Terminator need sunglasses?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93973/why-did-the-terminator-need-sunglasses/93978#93978) - *"Connor specifically looked for that model to send because he remembered him as such and wanted to make sure that he's doing what he was suppose to do - send the T-800 that he remembers back in time to 1995 so he can protect him from the T-1000. **He knew that for things to go the way they are suppose to, he has to find the terminator that looks like the one that he remembers."***

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The question of why a T-800 Model-101 (*Arnie-type*) Terminator was chosen is different in each of the films.

### Terminator

The T-800 in this film is a top-of-the-line model. It's literally the acme of what Skynet can produce and while there are indeed other models seen (particularly in the flashback sequence), the Arnie version is likely the *most* lifelike out of the bunch.

> **REESE:** *Pay attention.  The 600 series had rubber skin. We spotted them easy.  But these are new.  They look human.  Sweat, bad breath,
> everything.  Very hard to spot.  I had to wait 'til he moved on you
> before I could zero him.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Terminator: Film Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator.html)</sup></sub>

### Terminator 2: Judgement Day

It's circular, but John Connor chose to send back an identical model to the one that attacked his mother **because he (as an adult) remembered being saved by that model as a child**

> ***Connor specifically looked for that model to send because he
> remembered him as such** and wanted to make sure that he's doing what he
> was suppose to do - send the T-800 that he remembers back in time to
> 1995 so he can protect him from the T-1000. **He knew that for things to
> go the way they are suppose to, he has to find the terminator that
> looks like the one that he remembers.***
>
> <sub><sup>[T2FAQ: Interview with James Cameron](http://www.jamescamerononline.com/T2FAQ.htm)</sup></sub>

### Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines

There's no good indication of why Catherine Brewster chose to send back that *particular* Terminator other than that **it may have been the only upgraded T-850 (one with additional infiltration software) that they had immediate access to.**

We do know that the 'Arnie' exterior was chosen by Skynet because of John's "*emotional attachment*" to that particular model. It's not a stretch to imagine that **Catherine probably made the same judgement when she was deciding to send him back**.

> *"John Connor was terminated on July fourth, 2032," Terminator said. "I
> was selected for the emotional attachment he felt to my model number,
> due to his boyhood experiences. This aided in my infiltration."*
>
> <sub><sup>Terminator: Rise of the Machines - Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

### Terminator: Genisys

Two T-800s are seen in this film, one in the opening sequence (presumably chosen by Skynet for precisely the same reason as in Terminator) and one that was sent back by *persons unknown* to protect young Sarah Connor. We have no good intel on why this model was chosen (or [who it was sent by](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95419/who-sent-the-t-800-nicknamed-pops/95422#95422)) but I think we can assume that the fact that it's proven itself to be a reliable protector is a key factor.

Answer (score 7):

Terminator 3 had a deleted scene that explained Arnold as basis for T-800s.

**EDIT:** My answer is based off the TC first giving out of universe scenario:

> OK, OK, OK, I realize that the main plot to the story involved Arnold
>   schwarzenegger as the actor so it had to look like this.

and then based specifically on the actual question, and thought they were more or less wanting an in-universe answer.

> So was there anything canon that stated why all the Terminators that
>   were **sent back** looked the same?

The **future** 800 series model terminator in the dream sequence was never sent back.

http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Future_Terminator

If question was asking more why OTHER 800 series models weren't sent back instead of Arnold, the answer varies from movie to movie and has also been answered based on that framing of the question.

Comment: This is incredible!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. We see multiple T-800s that **don't** look like Arnie.

Comment: Yeah, the video is funny, but T3 is bad fan fiction.  The terminators were designed to be infiltrators.  It makes sense for Skynet to create them to infiltrate the human resistance.  But this video says that the robots are going to be put on the front lines.  So why bother making them look human?  It would add cost for no benefit, when simply painting the metal endoskeltons camouflage would provide a benefit for little cost.

Comment: You deserve all the +1s just to see Arnie doing a terrible southern accent!!! But yeah, this directly contradicts the point of the Terminators laid out in T1 and Reese's assertion that the T-800 was a new development during the war. Then again, by the time of T3 the timeline is so messed up who knows if T3 is even in T1 Reese's timeline?

Comment: @Schwern  Its not.  As the Terminator in T3 mentions T2 delayed Judgement Day. By that point there probably isn't much similarity beyond the existence of Skynet and it causing Judgement Day.

Answer (score 6):

**T2 Illustrated Screenplay**

Extended Future War Sequence - 5/10/90 draft

> INT COLD STORAGE ROOM
>
> Connor walks into the darkness, followed by a few technicians. They are in a vault-like cold-storage room. Hanging in steel racks from ceiling tracks are hundreds of what appear to be men. They are in rows of ten. Within each row, each of the bodies are absolutely identical.
>
> Connor signals the techs to remain by the door and walks out among the dark bodies. They are UNACTIVATED TERMINATORS. **He stops at a row in which they are identical to the terminator which was sent to kill Sarah** (the Arnold model).
>
> He walks to the end of a row. There is one empty rack. He faces the terminator in the next rack. Its eyes are closed.
> John seems distant as he studies that face.

[image]

([source](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5336955/terminator-2-storyboards-show-the-destruction-of-skynet/))

There's *only* two Terminator movies and a re-boot. That's why 'every' terminator sent back is a 101 model, other than the fact that as Kyle said, **"these are new."**

Comment: No matter how hard you try to deny it, there are *five* terminator films, not including the 3D stage-show which has more canon inconsistencies than you can shake a stick at.

Comment: Ok, I take it back. There's two movies, a re-boot, and a [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgV7-MJwUBw).

Comment: That trailer is better and more suspenseful than the entire Genisys film. Even the effects put the latest effort to shame.

Comment: It's [better than the rest of the whole shebang put together](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56849/who-designed-and-built-the-t-800-series-terminator-endoskeleton-prop/56855#56855), nor is it likely to ever be surpassed, given the 'advances' in CGI.